# Angular2 Input Validation and Feedback

Tags: angular

I've inherited a rather large project with template-driven forms without any input validation. I've got about 40 templates I need to convert to utilize input validation, and I've spent all week trying to find a way to convert them that isn't mind-numbingly tedious to implement and maintain. Most tutorials I've seen end with a bunch of *ngif elements for each possible error for a field, which is absolutely ridiculous.

The best solution I've found is to convert all forms to be reactive forms and then create a component that takes a FormControl and lists the errors relative to the control. But even with this, I still have to create an instance of the component after every single input field. This just seems so tedious and everything on npm just seems to add a bunch of cool means to set up validation, but always ends in a bunch of *ngif just like in the simplest tutorials for displaying error feedback.

Has anyone found a solution for input validation that isn't so tedious? I mean, input validation shouldn't be so hands on, it should just be a one and done. Is there anything that achieves universal input validation and feedback similar to standard jQuery solutions such as https://jqueryvalidation.org/ ?

Comment: standard jQuery solutions didn't work as expected.

Comment: Yeah,there doesn't seem to be an easy way to wrap jQuery plugins like you could do in Angular. I understand that fundamentally, jQuery and Angular shouldn't be mixed, but there is just a huge amount of reinventing the wheel needed in Angular2 to accomplish simple tasks. I'm spending way more time fiddling with Angular2 than actually developing an application, this wasn't the case with Angular.

Comment: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html

Comment: I know, it's incredibly unintuitive and tedious though. Do you really think it's a good practice to have to make an *ngif for every single possible error for each individual field? Like I said, I've looked at that tutorial and probably 20 others, and I feel it's not a good solution to have to have to manually code every possible error for each field relative to the state of the field.